# canvas set to "clientWidth," does not shrink when nearby element resizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a web application with a CSS grid based UI. In one of the grid sections, there is a collapsible side panel, and a canvas element that I want to always resize to fill the remaining space. The canvas updates every frame, so I'm setting the `canvas.width`, to the `clientWidth` of the wrapper div on every frame.

The canvas properly expands to fill the space when the panel is collapsed, but when the panel is opened back up again the canvas does not shrink, and instead overflows off the page. I have some theories about why this might be happening, such as the wrapper div refusing to shrink once the canvas has expanded, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the issue.

Here is a simple mockup of the problem:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script>
    let open = true;

    window.onload = () => {
        let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        canvasUpdate(canvas);
    }

    function canvasUpdate(canvas){
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas.width = document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").clientWidth;
        canvas.height = document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").clientHeight;

        ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(canvas.width - 50, canvas.height - 50, 50, 50);

        window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{canvasUpdate(canvas)});
    }

    function togglePanel(){
        if (open){
            document.getElementById("sidePanel").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("expandBtn").style.display = "block";
            open = false;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("sidePanel").style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementById("expandBtn").style.display = "none";
            open = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    html, body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #gridWrapper{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "header header"
            "col1 col2";
        grid-template-columns: 100pt 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 50pt minmax(0, 1fr);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #header{
        grid-area: header;
        background: #AAFFAA;
    }

    #col1{
        grid-area: col1;
        background: #FFAAAA;
    }

    #col2{
        grid-area: col2;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    #sidePanel{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #expandBtn{
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #canvasWrapper{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="gridWrapper">
        <div id="header">
            Header contents
        </div>
        <div id="col1">
            Col1 contents
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
            <div id="sidePanel">
                <div id="panelContents">
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                </div>
                <button id="collapseBtn" onclick="togglePanel()">
                    &lt;
                </button>
            </div>
            <button id="expandBtn" onclick="togglePanel()">
                &gt;
            </button>
            <div id="canvasWrapper">
                <canvas id="canvas">
                    //Error loading canvas
                </canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

if I set the grid's `overflow = hidden` it solves the issue of it running of the page, but the canvas still remains the expanded width.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. it seems like a block level element wont shrink to smaller than a canvas element no matter what CSS settings you set, but thankfully I found a workaround by temporarily setting the canvas w/h to 1, *then* getting and storing the dimensions of the wrapper, before finally setting the canvas to the stored dimensions.

```
    let wrapperBounds = {width:0,height:0};

    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;

    wrapperBounds.width = document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").clientWidth;
    wrapperBounds.height = document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").clientHeight;

    canvas.width = wrapperBounds.width;
    canvas.height = wrapperBounds.height;
```

I originally didn't think this would work since I figured automatic width was calculated at a different point in the life-cycle than `requestAnimationFrame()` but apparently CSS is calculated immediately after a change.

Full Code implementation:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script>
    let open = true;

    window.onload = () => {
        let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        canvasUpdate(canvas);
    }

    function canvasUpdate(canvas){
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        let wrapperBounds = {width:0,height:0};

        canvas.width = 1;
        canvas.height = 1;

        wrapperBounds.width = document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").clientWidth;
        wrapperBounds.height = document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").clientHeight;

        canvas.width = wrapperBounds.width;
        canvas.height = wrapperBounds.height;

        ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(canvas.width - 50, canvas.height - 50, 50, 50);

        window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{canvasUpdate(canvas)});
    }

    function togglePanel(){
        if (open){
            document.getElementById("sidePanel").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("expandBtn").style.display = "block";
            open = false;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("sidePanel").style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementById("expandBtn").style.display = "none";
            open = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    html, body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #gridWrapper{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "header header"
            "col1 col2";
        grid-template-columns: 100pt 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 50pt minmax(0, 1fr);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #header{
        grid-area: header;
        background: #AAFFAA;
    }

    #col1{
        grid-area: col1;
        background: #FFAAAA;
    }

    #col2{
        grid-area: col2;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    #sidePanel{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #expandBtn{
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #canvasWrapper{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="gridWrapper">
        <div id="header">
            Header contents
        </div>
        <div id="col1">
            Col1 contents
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
            <div id="sidePanel">
                <div id="panelContents">
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                    <div class="contents">Contents</div>
                </div>
                <button id="collapseBtn" onclick="togglePanel()">
                    &lt;
                </button>
            </div>
            <button id="expandBtn" onclick="togglePanel()">
                &gt;
            </button>
            <div id="canvasWrapper">
                <canvas id="canvas">
                    //Error loading canvas
                </canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```